# I can't find the Microsoft Excel Object Library in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Hello guys can somebody help me? I can't find the Microsoft Excel Object Library in the Com tab of add resources dialog even though I have already installed Microsoft Office. Please Please Please help me :)

Comment: where is your sample code ?

Comment: the code is too long actually. hehe. I just can't find the microsoft excel object library when i try to add it as a reference...

Comment: share the screen shot of your com tab. I can see MS excel object library in COM tab

Comment: .NET tab, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: how can i share the screen shot?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post image .. T.T

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mFvtC_JZkhTXI5bXZHZFRFNEk/edit?usp=sharing there's the image :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the VSTO-library (Visual Studio Tools for Office).